# Grid View: not aligning properly

Tags: css

So, I don't have enough reputation points to upload an image so I will try my best to explain it.

In the grid view (just like pinterest), each posts have different height. Even with the different height, all the posts fill the gap in between them (ie, no gap between them).

For my site, I have set up the following CSS for 4 posts horizontally:

```
.sample{
 float:left;
 width: 24%;
 margin-right:1%;
}
```

They line up properly horizontally, however, because they have all different height, they do not line up properly vertically (ie, lots of gaps).

I am not sure how to change the code so that regardless of the height of posts in the grid view, they always line up both vertically and horizontally.

Thanks.

EDIT:

From the desktop, please go to http://sevek.staging.wpengine.com/mobile/?wptouch_preview_theme=enabled then just resize the window to make it look like a mobile version.

This (the main page) is the working version which is what I am trying to copy.

When you resize the screen width, all the items align nicely and there is no gap.

Now, please go to here (which is what I am trying to fix) then resize the width to 840px:

http://sevek.staging.wpengine.com/profile/sevek/?wptouch_preview_theme=enabled

As you will see, grid view posts are not aligned properly and there is gap.

Comment: can you give us the HTML as well??

Comment: Hi. I edited the original post which now includes the site url. Thanks! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to do it on your code, but it needs a lot of clean-up as you have many values overwrites with !important, overwritten with another !important and so on. I suggest starting from scratch at least for your "user-posts" class followed by its first level children,

```
.userpro-posts {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 2em auto;
    -moz-column-count:3;
    -moz-column-gap: 3%;
    -moz-column-width: 30%;
    -webkit-column-count:3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 3%;
    -webkit-column-width: 30%;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 3%;
    column-width: 30%;
}

.userpro-post {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

(you can set as many columns you want,but you'll may need some JS as well for different screen sizes)

remove all that unneeded code and follow this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/7Chkz/. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! =) it certainty did!